# Hardware keyboard crashes app

Tags: android

I've noticed that in my application, when I add a hardware keyboard, the app closes. Since this doesn't happen in other apps, I'm assuming there's a solution I'm not aware of. The error log from the crash is below. Any ideas for a solution?

```
04-07 02:55:07.885 I/Process (4121): Sending signal. PID: 4121 SIG: 9
04-07 02:55:07.915 W/InputDispatcher(498): channel '41c28930 com.prapps.inventory/com.prapps.inventory.InventoryActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
04-07 02:55:07.915 E/InputDispatcher(498): channel '41c28930 com.prapps.inventory/com.prapps.inventory.InventoryActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-07 02:55:07.925 W/InputDispatcher(498): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '41c28930 com.prapps.inventory/com.prapps.inventory.InventoryActivity (server)'
04-07 02:55:07.925 I/ActivityManager(498): Process com.prapps.inventory (pid 4121) has died.
04-07 02:55:07.925 W/ActivityManager(498): Force removing ActivityRecord{416c8930 u0 com.prapps.inventory/.InventoryActivity}: app died, no saved state
04-07 02:55:07.925 I/WindowState(498): WIN DEATH: Window{41c28930 u0 com.prapps.inventory/com.prapps.inventory.InventoryActivity}
04-07 02:55:08.015 W/InputMethodManagerService(498): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 4121 uid 10037
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are unregistering your keyboard twice, hence the `"Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel"`.
To solve this, I would suggest you go through your code and try to look for a call of the unregister method and delete it (presumably the second call).

I hope this helps.

Comment: In addition to the above solution, I solved the problem by adding
`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"` to the main activity in the manifest.